# Is it possible to use Redemption.dll without admin rights?

Tags: com, outlook-redemption, regfreecom

I have downloaded the redemption.dll and it needs to be added with regsvr32.exe, however lacking the admin rights to do so, I'm wondering if there's any other way to access Redemption in Outlook's VBA?

Answer (score 0):

Redemption is a COM based library which requires to be registered on the system to be able to consume it from the VBA code.

You may consider using the [Registry-free COM](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption/security.htm#regfreecom) technology in case of using the Redemption library from .Net based applications or VB, but not VBA.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Redemption can be installed without admin right using regsvr32.exe. By default, it tries to install itself in HKCR/HKLM, if it can't - it installs in HKCU.